# how execute smart contract step by step?

Tags: blockchain, mining, evm

I have a few problems understanding the step of execution of transaction in smart contract.

1-When a user send a transaction to smart contract, this smart contract is not executed immediately instead is it pooled in a transaction pool.

2- At some point of time, every EVM is chosen an transaction to execute the code in smart contract line by line.

3-If all EVMS find the same result, **what happens after?** Else the smart contract cancelled this transaction.

**what happens after?** ==> 4- the miner would collect all transactions from transaction pool,  and adds them to the newly created block and then the mining process starts between miners.( correct me if I'm wrong please in the steps)

5-finally, the blockchain is transitioned into a new state.

*How does the miner verify that these transactions are well executed by EVM?

*Does EVM play the role only in the first part of the execution of smart contract?

*Who will change state when the contract is executed? ( transaction ?)

Answer (score 4):

You've misunderstood the steps. But close!

Consensus is easily misunderstood.

The fundamental problem first solved by Bitcoin was how to reach eventual consensus among nodes that do not know or necessarily trust each other. Add money to the environment and it becomes an adversarial environment. This is in no way like the situation in a typical cluster of computers that *do* know each other and *do* trust each other.

We get a *hint* about how to solve it from transaction logs employed by databases. If one has a replayable log with all the inputs in the right order, then one can reconstruct a database. It's not important to have "the state" if you have the inputs that created that state.

There is a non-obvious challenge to deal with. Given physics, it is not possible for all nodes to learn about all transactions at the same time or even in the same order. It will (probably) never be possible to make everything as fast or faster than everything else.

In a trustful environment, that could be resolved with accurate, trustworthy timestamps that would help everyone enumerate the "correct" transaction order. In an adversarial environment with no authority, that doesn't work because no one's clock is considered more trustworthy than anyone else's.

So, how to order the transactions?

The mining process collapses that ambiguity. The "winning" miner earns the privilege of setting a de facto network transaction order, for one block. Importantly, this is not even an attempt to resolve the temporal order of transactions. In fact, gasPrice, is a way to queue jump. One can *probably* incentivize a miner to include a transaction sooner by attaching a high bid. Conversely, one can save on transaction fees by being patient.

*Nothing* happens anywhere until nodes receive news of transactions included in blocks. Transactions in blocks are well-ordered. The blocks themselves are well-ordered. So, the chain of blocks is a well-ordered set of all transactions that have *happened*.

Each full node, not just the miners, processes transactions completely, reaching their own conclusions about state changes. This is very much like replaying a transaction log because everyone agrees on the inputs and the order of those inputs. The functions are deterministic (strict requirement) so there can be no disagreement between well-functioning nodes at the same block height.

Blocks have time-stamps but transactions don't. Block time is the minimal resolution, and all that can be said is that all transactions in a block were mined at that block time, in the order of inclusion. Each transaction executed in the context left by the previous transaction.

Miners have non-trivial privilege. Working together they can censor transactions. They can play with timestamps and transaction order, if there is selfish benefit doing so. This can be important in contract design when factors such as "deadline" exist.

In any case, the consensus resolves transaction order. Nodes figure out the state for themselves.

Hope it helps.

p.s. There is a lot more going on in mining but I wanted to focus on your question.

Comment: Can you please explain this sentence: Each full node, not just the miners, **processes transactions** completely. how processes transactions ??
But from what I read and in this link: [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16990/is-the-execution-of-a-smart-contract-performed-by-the-miner-or-the-blockchain )
The smart contract is executed within the EVM, . The results of the execution should be exactly the same to add the transactions to the blockchain. I need a help to better understand Sir.

Comment: Also says, `Each node of the network, not only miners execute the smart contracts.` The EVM is in every node, and the nodes form a swarm. This might help bring it into view: https://www.bitrates.com/guides/ethereum/what-is-the-unstoppable-world-computer

Comment: To correct what I said at the beginning and from what I understood,when a miner receives transaction, it runs transaction on EVM and includes result of transaction in block to mine. Then, block eventually mined and added to Blockchain (if miner happens to successfly mine this block). Finaly, everyone copies the new block and verifies it by running EVM ( the transaction that go to the network they are run lots of times by everyone run it in EVMs to verify the transaction. I got the same output to check evrey think is okay)                  correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: It's almost right but I think there is confusion. Pardon me if I'm mistaken. This: `and includes result of transaction in block to mine` - completely misstated. It does not "include the result". It includes the transaction ... more specifically, it includes the inputs (from Alice, to Bob, amount, data ... signature) - not the result. This is not in a block "to mine". The miner's job is "to mine". The miner includes the transaction inputs in a transaction that "was mined." Yes, the miner runs the transaction. That's because _all nodes_ run the transaction and "all nodes" includes the miner.

Comment: The transaction was included in a block, the block was transmitted to everyone. Everyone runs the transaction, including the miner. The miner was the first to know the transaction was included in a block, so it was the first the run it. No one cares what the miner thinks the transaction does. They will run it themselves to find out.

Comment: Yes sir, I mean the transaction. but where miner includes the transaction inputs?, I do not understand this: ` the miner includes the transaction inputs in a transaction that "was mined." ` i.e not in the block? so , where and then run transaction. what do you meaning of `all nodes run the transaction and "all nodes" includes the miner ` ?

Comment: I need this answer sir to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93725/discussion-between-rob-hitchens-and-amira).

Comment: @RobHitchens This is an old question, but I hope you will respond. I think you are mistaken when saying that `and includes result of the transaction in block to mine` is wrong. As a matter of fact, when computing a transaction the results are stored in miner's/validator's Receipt Trie whose root is included in the header of the block the current validator/miner is assembling, meaning that the result of the transaction is indeed in a sense "included" in the block (in the case given miner's/validator's block gets accepted). Maybe I misunderstood you, but would appreciate your response!

Comment: Perhaps not worded very clearly. There is a merkle root that does indeed flow from the result of the transaction, but it is very lossy. You cannot determine that x=4 in a certain contract with nothing but the merkle root. But, you cannot generate the merkle root without _knowing_ that x=4, so you run the transaction to find out.

Comment: @RobHitchens Thanks, great then indeed we agree on the same! Perhaps, you would like to take a look at my other question (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136406/how-are-beaconblocks-and-beaconstates-interconnected) I think it is quite technical and I am having problems finding answers to it.