# How are BeaconBlocks and BeaconStates interconnected?

Tags: blockchain, beacon-chain, state, the-merge

After the Ethereum merge took place, the original blockchain merged into the Beacon chain and its data is referenced under the `execution_payload` field in the `class BeaconBlock(...)` and the Beacon chain officially became the main chain for settlement of transactions and contracts.

Nonethless, we also have the state or the `class BeaconState(...)` which is supposed to be "monolithic" container for all of the most important things regarding the Ethereum's state at the given moment.

Now, the objects of type `BeaconState` have to co-exist somehow in the system with the rest of the segments. My question is, how are the objects of the type `BeaconState` interconnected among themselves and how do they connect or interact with the `BeaconBlock`s? Are they somehow referenced in the `BeaconBlock` or are they stored somewhere completely differently, just somewhere in e.g. LevelDB and retrieved when necessary? Also, how often are they instantiated or only one object is edited always?

Answer (score 1):

The [BeaconState](https://eth2book.info/latest/part3/containers/state#beaconstate) is a single object that is maintained by the consensus client. It contains everything that needs to be persisted in order to run the proof of stake protocol, such as information about validator balances, nonces, validator statuses, info about justification and finality.

The beacon state does not directly contain anything to do with the execution state which is maintained by the execution client (the execution state contains Ethereum account balances, smart contracts, and all of the execution layer stuff), except a little bit of info about the deposit contract. However, the beacon state does contain the latest execution payload header, which includes the state root of the execution state. So this ties a particular beacon state to a particular execution state, ensuring that the two clients are always in lock-step.

It's fair to say that maintaining the beacon state is the primary function of consensus clients.

The relationship between beacon blocks and the beacon state is simple. The consensus client maintains the beacon state by processing beacon blocks (in order).

The consensus specification defines a [state transition function](https://eth2book.info/latest/part3/containers/state#beaconstate):

```
post_state = state_transition(pre_state, block)
```

That is, you take your beacon state (`pre_state`) and a beacon block (`block`) and feed them into the state transition function. The result is your updated beacon state (`post_state`). This process is completely deterministic: given a beacon state and a block you will always end up with the same resulting beacon state - it is a "pure" function. This is done every time a block is received - normally every 12 seconds (there is a special process for updating the state after an empty slot, but conceptually it's the same).

Clients are free to implement all this however they like. Typically they might keep some recent versions of the beacon state available in case there are forks that need to be processed: we might sometimes need to "rewind", or "unapply" one or more blocks - the easiest way to do this is just to keep the old pre-states around. For example, you might cache a small number of beacon states in memory (a beacon state is currently about 50MB in size), store on disk all beacon states since the chain last finalised, and discard all beacon states before finalisation. That would be a "pruning" node. An "archive" node might store older beacon states back to genesis. A pruning node can always be turned into an archive node - all you have to do is replay blocks from genesis onwards.